# DOS batchfile needed to unzip a directory of files and rename

Tags: dos

I have a directory of zip files ( 60 ) that when opened/unzipped a lot of them and to my SHOCK have the same name like Jim.txt & Jim.txt. I need to unzip each one, rename it to something orginal like file 1, file 2 etc for all the zip files in the directory . Have downlaoded the winzip command line utility for DOS so unzipping from DOS is done like this, "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip\wzunzip" FILNEAME.zip . So in pseudo code :

Take File1.zip .
Unzip it 
Rename it to File1 
Take File2.zip
Unzip it 
Rename it to File2
And loop same until all zip files done .

The question is how to code this in a DOS batch file ?

Comment: Please clarify your pseudo code.  You just want to remove the .zip extension from file1.zip after you unzip it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by the following batch file created ....

::Setup the stage...
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET folder=C:\P\DataSource2_W
SET count=1

::Action
CD "%folder%"
FOR %%F IN ("*.zip") DO (

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip\wzunzip" %%F
  MOVE *.txt "C:\P\DataSource2_W\TextFiles!count!.txt"
  SET /a count=!count!+1
)
ENDLOCAL